# Tkinter Button disable does not work

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Hi i am trying to disable a button , so that the command event does not work for some time .How can i make the button disabled for some time and then later reenable it , to get the callback function .

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk

import time


class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.b1 = Button(self, text="Press Me!",command = self.callback)

        self.count=0 
        self.but_flag=0
        self.b1.grid()

    def callback(self):
        self.b1['state'] = DISABLED
        for k in range(5):
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print k
        self.b1['state'] = NORMAL


mainw = Tk()
mainw.f = MyFrame(mainw)
mainw.f.grid()
mainw.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `sleep` in your `callback` function is blocking the UI from refreshing. Instead of using `sleep`, you could schedule the re-enabling of the button using `after`.

```
def callback(self):
    self.b1['state'] = DISABLED
    self.after(3000, self.enable)

def enable(self):
    self.b1['state'] = NORMAL
```

But if you do any long-running task in `callback`, this will still freeze the UI.

Another alternative would be to create a worker thread for doing the actual work. This way, the UI thread is not blocked and the UI will be updated and the button deactivated/activated.

```
def callback(self):
    threading.Thread(target=self.do_actual_work).start()

def do_actual_work(self):
    self.b1['state'] = DISABLED
    for i in range(5):
        print i
        time.sleep(1)
    self.b1['state'] = NORMAL
```

Of course, you could also just add `self.b1.update()` after the disabling line to update the Button widget to its disabled state, but this will still leave the UI frozen until the method is finished.

Comment: i ideally want to disable the button and then complete another routine while which the button should not be clickable , the after function wont let that happen i suppose , i am basically using python on Raspi .. so on clicking the button the motor starts and then i want to disable the button ,.. till the motor stops ..and then reenable it .

Comment: @Deepworks Then your real question is a bit different from the one you asked. You could run `self.update_idletasks()` after `self.b1['state'] = DISABLED`, then the state is updated and you will see the disabled button. But do keep in mind that as long as a callback function does not return, your Tkinter GUI remains unresponsive.

Comment: i got it working using self.b1['state'] = DISABLED  self.nav_button[0].update()

Comment: @Deepworks Using `update` will update that particular button, but your UI will still be non-responsive until the task has finished.